# Tensorflow: ImportError cannot import name graph_util in retrain.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

I compiled Tensorflow from source to work with GPU. I was able to successfully install it. It's able to successfully run the sample mnist `convolutional.py` script.

However, when I do the `retrain.py` script in `tensorflow/examples/image_retraining`, it spits out the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retrain.py", line 70, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import graph_util
ImportError: cannot import name graph_util
```

With command and other output:

```
$ python retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=gpu_train/bottlenecks \
--model_dir=inception \
--output_graph=gpu_train/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=gpu_train/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir categories
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.dylib locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retrain.py", line 70, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import graph_util
ImportError: cannot import name graph_util
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/a558c6e3b38846727873b5afbbc3ba309ae5dff5) yesterday which moved the file `graph_util.py` from `tensorflow.python.client` to `tensorflow.python.framework`.

It is weird that you have the old version of `retrain.py` with the import `from tensorflow.python.client import graph_util`, but have also `graph_util.py` moved.

---

Anyway, the [master version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L70) of `graph_util.py` is up to date (with `from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util`) so you should get the newest version (no need to compile again, just pull).

Comment: It seems that if you are running the python 2.7 sources you will still need to change the import package of the graph_util.py to the tensorfloy.python.client manually on the file retrain.py