# Tensorflow: ImportError for graph_util from tensorflow.python.framework

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to go through the [TensorFlow for Poets Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html) on OS X El Capitan, Python 2.7 (via HomeBrew), and TensorFlow 0.9.0. Instead of using Docker as instructed, I installed TensorFlow with pip and I cloned the [tensorflow repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) into my working folder.

To [re-train the network](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4), I run the following command:

```
python tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos
```

Which fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 80, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
ImportError: cannot import name graph_util
```

In my Python shell, I am able to verify that TensorFlow is installed correctly by importing `tensorflow`, `tensor_shape` from `tensorflow.python.framework`, and `gfile` from `tensorflow.python.platform` (as in the [retraining script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)). Trying to import `graph_util` results in the same error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
# Success
>>> from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
# Success
>>> from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
# Success
>>> from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name graph_util
```

What could be the reason for this?

Edit: Opened [issue #3203](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3203) on the tensorflow repo. Seems like this is a bug.

Note: [This older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850347/tensorflow-importerror-cannot-import-name-graph-util-in-retrain-py) asks about the same error, but refers a different TensorFlow library with a  retraining script which tries to import `graph_util` from `tensorflow.python.client` (see also [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/a558c6e3b38846727873b5afbbc3ba309ae5dff5#diff-e27def9997dcd569e1f2412fd6f3ae76) to the TensorFlow source).

Comment: This means that the `graph_util` method is not defined under `tensorflow.python.framework`.

Comment: @super_cr7 `graph_util` it is not a method, it is a file that defines several methods; and it is [there in the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util.py). I can't see any [changes that would affect `graph_util` since the 0.9.0 release](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/compare/v0.9.0...r0.9) (which is the version I have installed).

Comment: I apologise for my naivety. It'll be better to ask as an issue on the github repo, or ask on https://stats.stackexchange.com and other related communities.

Comment: @super_cr7 No need to apologise, you would be right in many cases - an honest mistake =) I will open an issue on the repo if I can't get to a solution here, but I doubt that stats will be the appropriate community for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Since this was the number 1 google result for me when I searched for this problem, I'll suggest a workaround which works (until tensorflow/examples get updated):

In `examples/image_retraining/retrain.py`

```
CHANGE
from `tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util`
TO
from `tensorflow.python.client import graph_util`
```

There is a commit now present in the tensorflow master to move graph_util from client to framework, so this workaround should not be required in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. Once I did this

```
replace    from `tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util`
with       from `tensorflow.python.client import graph_util`
```

this below mentioned issue was gone.

```
File "retrain.py", line 75, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
ImportError: cannot import name graph_util
```

and new one came up.

```
File "retrain.py", line 1042, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'argv'
```

To resolve this I replaced entire content of [retain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) file (from master branch) with [retain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) file (from r0.9 branch).

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem as yours, and I used the following two steps to solve the problem：

1. Activate TensorFlow，and stay active during following steps as well as running retrain.py：
   source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate # bash, sh, ksh, or zsh
2. Upgrade TensorFlow version by those steps:

   (tensorflow)$ easy_install -U pip

   (tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow # for Python 2.7

Reference tensorflow official link:https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux